# Combine 2 column values in 1 to many into new row in new table - SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, one-to-many

I have an SQL script in oracle which is almost complete but I am stuck on one last issue.

I have 2 database tables I am accessing data from, and inserting the new rows into a new table in my database.
One of the database tables has an account number column and a descriptor column, and each account number has 3 descriptor values, all with the same format. There is a third column as well which I want to grab data from.  Here is a visual:

```
Account # | Descriptor           | Value
1           Cost Center: ASDF      CC123
1           Company: ASDF123       F123
1           Fund: JKL              R123
2           Cost Center: ASDF12    CC456
2           Company: ASDF456       F456
2           Fund: JKL23            R456
```

I would like my final table to be like this:

```
Account_Number | Company_Description   |  Cost_Center_Value
1                Company: ASDF123         CC123
2                Company: ASDF456         CC456
```

The elements for the Cost_Center_Value column and the Company_Description column come from different rows, but the same account object.

The issue I am having is that I have a special `where` clause to help me extract only the descriptor row with the 'Company:' text. If I put in an `AND`, the table is not populated at all, I think because it expects the data to be in the same row, when I want data from 2 rows but different columns. If I use and `OR` statement, it adds an entire new row.

Here is my script:

```
    create table mydb.test1 as
select distinct substr(testdb.table1.FAO, 1) as Account_Number,
       'CM' || substr(testdb.table1.DESCRIPTOR, 18) as Division,
       substr(testdb.table1.value, 1) as Department,
       substr(testdb.table2.Workday_Description, 1) as Description,

  from testdb.table1
       join testdb.table2
           on testdb.table1.fao = testdb.table2.workday_number
           where testdb.table2.descriptor like 'Company for%'
           OR testdb.table1.value like 'CC%'
           order by Account_Number Desc
```

I left the OR statement in there to show what I have been playing around with.
That is the closest I can get.

If more info is needed, let me know.

Comment: Why does your description of the problem show a single table, but your query attempt has two tables, with several unmentioned columns?

Comment: @Laurence - I only put the important stuff in the post. I don't think the other table and columns are needed, but I can add them if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is to learn about normal form and redesign this database. However you could do something hideous like:

```
Select
    Account_Number,
    max(Case 
        When Descriptor Like 'Company: %' then substr(Descriptor, 10, 1000) 
    end) Company_Description,
    max(Case 
        When Descriptor Like 'Cost Center: %' then value 
    end) Cost_Center_Value
From
    test -- this is the table in the example section
Group By
    Account_Number
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e0cb/3)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

You could create a subquery, which selects only the account number and Cost Center value of each account, and then query that.

This is not perfect, but it might give you an idea of what I'm thinking:

```
    create table mydb.test1 as
select distinct substr(testdb.table1.FAO, 1) as Account_Number,
       'CM' || substr(testdb.table1.DESCRIPTOR, 18) as Division,
       substr(testdb.table1.value, 1) as Department,
       substr(testdb.table2.Workday_Description, 1) as Description,

  from testdb.table1
       join (
       select [ACCOUNT], [COST_CENTER_VALUE] 
       from [TABLE] 
       where Descriptor LIKE 'Cost Center%') a
       on a.account_number = table1.account_number
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
create table mydb.test1 as
select distinct
account as Account_Number,
(select (case when t2.Description like 'Company%' then t2.description end) from testdb.table1 t2 where t1.account=t2.account and 
case when t2.Description like 'Company%' then t2.description end is not null)as Company_Description ,
(select (case when t2.Description like 'Cost Center%' then t2.value end) from testdb.table1 t2 where t1.account=t2.account and 
case when t2.Description like 'Cost Center%' then t2.value end is not null)as Cost_Center_Value
from testdb.table1 t1;
```